# ffmpeg overlay duration issue

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I am making a setting (using anothergui) to burn in an overlay movie:

```
-i "<SourceFileName>" 
-i "Pathto\overlay1080.mov" 
-filter_complex overlay=shortest=0
-y 
-vcodec prores -profile:v 3 
-qscale:v 1
-acodec pcm_s16le -ar 48000 -ac 2 

"<OutputPath>\forCompFolder\<OutputFileName>.mov"
```

The compositing is fine, but the overlay video is 999 frames long and the first input video is shorter.  When I render it opts for the length of the overlay video.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you like it to do instead?

Comment: I would like it to only render to the duration of the first input (-i "<SourceFileName>" )

Comment: In this case change `shortest=0` to `shortest=1`. If the main input is always shorter than the overlay input then this will work for all of your other inputs. If the main input is longer than the overlay, then you'll need to use the [`eof_action`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) option in overlay.

Comment: It did not work.  It is still making the length that of the overlay video. I suspect it has to do with the order of the filter or something.  I tried doing some variables and setting it more explicitly.  I will keep trying at it though.  Thanks for the help.